# DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable]

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub, amazon-kinesis

I have a spring cloud stream app which consumes from azure eventhub and publish to aws kinesis data stream, and we are using spring cloud stream binders for both, I am getting below error

```
2023-12-03 19:19:04.335 ERROR 4225 --- [ition-pump-31-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.KinesisMessageHandler@37316ae0]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=FluxPeekFuseable, headers={azure_eventhubs_sequence_number=398, aeg-delivery-count=0, aeg-event-type=Notification, azure_checkpointer=com.azure.spring.messaging.checkpoint.AzureCheckpointer@7fde2d62, azure_raw_partition_id=31, aeg-output-event-id=d90abc61-c3ec-442b-92b3-a5585c5c1c23, azure_eventhubs_last_enqueued_event_properties=com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.models.LastEnqueuedEventProperties@3274f57a, x-opt-enqueued-time=2023-12-02T14:34:20.835Z, target-protocol=kafka, x-opt-sequence-number-epoch=-1, aeg-metadata-version=1, x-opt-sequence-number=398, aeg-subscription-name=B900292C-00B7-4ECC-B8D3-4267873F10A7, azure_eventhubs_enqueued_time=2023-12-02T14:34:20.835Z, aeg-data-version=1.0, x-opt-offset=4328017248, id=93dd477b-b5c4-2aa7-74b5-cf0126060bef, contentType=application/json, azure_eventhubs_offset=4328017248, timestamp=1701611344331}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.send(AbstractDestinationResolvingMessagingTemplate.java:72)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.doSendMessage(FunctionConfiguration.java:619)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:602)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:216)
    at com.azure.spring.integration.eventhubs.inbound.EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter.access$700(EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter.java:78)
    at com.azure.spring.integration.eventhubs.inbound.EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter.java:247)
    at com.azure.spring.integration.eventhubs.inbound.EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(EventHubsInboundChannelAdapter.java:228)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventProcessorClientBuilder$1.processEvent(EventProcessorClientBuilder.java:756)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.PartitionPumpManager.processEvent(PartitionPumpManager.java:301)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.PartitionPumpManager.processEvents(PartitionPumpManager.java:366)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.PartitionPumpManager.lambda$startPartitionPump$2(PartitionPumpManager.java:257)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.ConvertingFromMessageConverter.fromMessage(ConvertingFromMessageConverter.java:43)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.KinesisMessageHandler.buildPutRecordRequest(KinesisMessageHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.KinesisMessageHandler.handleMessageToAws(KinesisMessageHandler.java:179)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.outbound.AbstractAwsMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractAwsMessageHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60)
    ... 49 more
```

below is the binder function.

```
    @Bean
    public Function<Message<String>, String> connect() {
        return message -> {

            try {

                LOGGER.info("data consumed from eventhubs");

                String payload = message.getPayload();

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(payload);

                return data.toString();

            }catch (Exception ex){

                ex.printStackTrace();
                LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
                metricsProviderService.publishErrorMetric(ex);

                JSONObject errors = new JSONObject();

                errors.put("message", ex.getMessage());
                errors.put("stack", Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));

                errors.put("payload", message.getPayload());

                errors.getJSONObject("headers").put("tenant", "error_data");

                return errors.toString();
            }

        };
    }
```

below is the application configuration

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      credential:
        client-id: ${EVENTHUBS_CLIENT_ID}
        client-secret: ${EVENTHUBS_CLIENT_SECRET}
      profile:
        tenant-id: ${EVENTHUBS_TENANT_ID}
      eventhubs:
        namespace: ${EVENTHUBS_NAMESPACE}
        processor:
          checkpoint-store:
            container-name: ${AZURE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME}
            account-name: ${AZURE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME}
            sas-token: ${AZURE_BLOB_SAS_TOKEN}
    stream:
      function:
        definition: connect
      bindings:
        connect-in-0:
          binder: eventhubs
          destination: ${EVENTHUBS_NAME}
          group: ${EVENTHUBS_CONSUMER_GROUP}
        connect-out-0:
          binder: kinesis
          destination: ${AWS_KINESIS_DATA_STREAM}
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            use-native-encoding: true
            headerMode: none
      eventhubs:
        bindings:
          connect-in-0:
            consumer:
              track-last-enqueued-event-properties: true
              checkpoint:
                mode: MANUAL
      kinesis:
        binder:
          checkpoint:
            table: ${APP_PREFIX}-meta-data-store
          locks:
            table: ${APP_PREFIX}-lock-registry
    kinesis:
      binder:
        kpl-kcl-enabled: true

cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: ${AWS_REGION}
    stack:
      auto: false
```

can someone help me with this please.

I tried configuring a message serializer but didn't found any property to pass it.